# Tabbar background image transparent become white

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

i've created a custom tab bar by creating an background image and then in my appDelegate used this code

```
UITabBar *tabBar = [UITabBar appearance];
tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar"];
```

## image

[image]

the color around the round top is all transparent, but when in the app it automatically make it white and therefor it does not look so good in a tableview when scrolling. Can i keep it transparent in ios?

the only tabbar code i have beside the upon is following

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil]
 setTitleTextAttributes:
 @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
   NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Regular" size:18]
   }
 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this problem setting the translucent property of the tab bar to false.

You can make set it using the inspector from storyboard or by code:

```
tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
```

Hope that it helps.